# Average by group for 'n' number of rows per group - R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, average

I have a dataframe with three columns; `entity, date, value.`

First I must order the 'value' based on 'Descending order of 'DATE'' per entity.

Then,the requirement is to get ***2 types of averages per entity*** based on the user defined number of rows. For example, if user enters 3 and 6; it means that '**give me the average of first 3 values** and then **average of next 6 values**' per entity.

for the given dataset, result would be a data frame as:

```
    Entity    Avg3 Avg6
        A     110   65 
        B     220  130
```

I can use '`aggregate`' function to get '`mean`' by entity but I am not able to extract specific rows data per entity.
Also, `ordering` the dataframe based on entity and then 'date' seems to not work.

```
#order data based on date (tried adding entity here but it does not work)
df_new <- df[rev(order(as.Date(df$Date)))),]
```

here is the dput:

```
structure(list(Wells = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B"), Date = structure(c(1577836800, 1577923200, 1578009600, 
1578096000, 1578182400, 1578268800, 1578355200, 1578441600, 1578528000, 
1578614400, 1578700800, 1578787200, 1577836800, 1577923200, 1578009600, 
1578096000, 1578182400, 1578268800, 1578355200, 1578441600, 1578528000, 
1578614400, 1578700800, 1578787200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Index = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 
90, 100, 110, 120, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 
220, 240)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do but it sounds like by combing the length function and row means function you might get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Assuming we have dynamic inputs ('n1', 'n2'), `arrange` the data by 'Wells' and in `desc`ending order of 'Date', `group_by` the 'Well', use `slice_head` to get the first (`n1 + n2`) rows, then `summarise` to create the 'Avg' `mean` columns by taking the `head` and `tail` of 'Index' based on the 'n1' and 'n2' respectively

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
n1 <- 3
n2 <- 6
df %>%
    arrange(Wells, desc(Date)) %>% 
    group_by(Wells) %>%
    slice_head(n = n1 + n2) %>%
    summarise(!! str_c('Avg', n1) := mean(head(Index, n1)), 
              !! str_c('Avg', n2)  := mean(tail(Index, n2)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Wells  Avg3  Avg6
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       110    65
#2 B       220   130
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1 <- df[order(df$Wells, -as.numeric(df$Date)),]
out <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Index ~ Wells, 
       subset(df1, ave(seq_along(Wells), 
         Wells, FUN = seq_along) <= (n1 + n2)), FUN = function(x)
        c(Avg3 = mean(head(x, n1)), Avg6 = mean(tail(x, n2)))))
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. Thnx. Also thnx for providing non-dpylr answer. I did have to use 'slice' instead of 'slice_head'. My dplyr version couldn't find the function.

Comment: @CodeMaster I think it is from the new version.  You can change it to `slice(seq_len(n1 + n2))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut`/`findInterval` to divide data into groups, take `mean` of each group and get data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- c(3, 6)

df %>%
  arrange(Wells, desc(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Wells) %>%
  group_by(grp = findInterval(row_number(), cumsum(n), left.open = TRUE), .add = TRUE) %>%
  #For older dplyr version use add = TRUE
  #group_by(grp = findInterval(row_number(), cumsum(n), left.open = TRUE), add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Index = mean(Index)) %>%
  slice(seq_along(n)) %>%
  mutate(grp = paste0('avg', n)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Index)

#  Wells  avg3  avg6
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       110    65
#2 B       220   130
```